# Magento 2: Set product stock programmatically

Tags: stock, magento-2.1.2

I have to setup Product 'in stock' and update Quantity programmatically. Here is my code I am trying:

```
$product->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
$product->setData('qty', 5);
$product->save();
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Can you please try below code? It will save inventory data.

```
$product->setStockData(['qty' => $stockData, 'is_in_stock' => $stockData]);
$product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => $stockData, 'is_in_stock' => $stockData]);
$product->save();
```

Comment: Thanks SH Patel, I used last three line of above code and it works for me.

Comment: I used only first and third line but it not worked. the second line is also important to get it work.

Comment: I used second line and third line and it is working, so first line `$product->setStockData(['qty' => $stockData, 'is_in_stock' => $stockData])` is unnecessary. @shashank

Comment: This code working for me bit only for enable product quantity update. Which products are disable, it's quantity not update. Can you help me for solve it.

Answer (score 2):

***In Magento 2.3 was deprecated change stock directly via setStockData(...)
Instead of it, you MUST use this way for updating product stock***

1. Init product stock repository

```
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\InventoryApi\Api\StockRepositoryInterface $productStockRepository
    ) {
        $this->productStockRepository = $productStockRepository;
    }
```

2. Use Repository for product stock update

```
    $productStock = $productStockRepository->get($entity->getId());
    $productStock->setStockData(['is_in_stock' => false]);
    $productStockRepository->save($productStock);
```

***In case if you don't use Multi Source Inventory (Magento_InventoryApi extesions), you can update product stock this way:***

1. Init product stock registry

```
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\InventoryApi\Api\StockRepositoryInterface $productStockRepository
    ) {
        $this->productStockRepository = $productStockRepository;
    }
```

2. Get product stock item and change product stock

```
    $productStock = $productStockRegistry->getStockItem($entity->getId());
    $productStock = $productStockRepository->get($entity->getId());
    $productStock->setIsInStock(true);
    $productStock->setQty(10);
    $productStock->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento latest version uses the MSI inventory module for managing the inventory. Also providing provisions to create multiple inventory sources. By default, It will use the default source. If you want to set or update product stock then use the below code.

```
public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\InventoryCatalogApi\Model\SourceItemsProcessorInterface $sourceItemsProcessor
) {
    .....
    $this->sourceItemsProcessor = $sourceItemsProcessor;
}
public function execute()
{
    $data = [
        ['source_code'=>'default', 'status'=>1, 'quantity'=>50],
    ];
    
    $this->sourceItemsProcessor->execute(
        'your_sku',
        $data
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions are workable but they are **deprecated**.

So, You may follow the links below. I found these ones helpful.

```
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/325544/proper-way-to-update-stock-in-2-4
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272296/how-to-set-qty-to-product-on-msi-magento-2-3
```