# What is the fastest way to update stock in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to update product stock in Magento 2 (2.4). But it is slow. I've used these 2 different methods:

- [Proper way to update stock in >= 2.4?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/325544/proper-way-to-update-stock-in-2-4) » Valid for Magento > 2.3
- [Magento 2: Programmatically Updating Inventory](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96519/magento-2-programmatically-updating-inventory) » Deprecated for Magento > 2.2

Both options take a lot of time to update each item ( > 1.5 seconds). Is there a faster way to update stocks? Something like the saveAttribute function we use for products?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: did you find better and fastest way ?